# How to run react-native run-ios with specific target

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

Is there a way to run a specific target with command

```
react-native run-ios
```

for Android I'm using following

```
react-native run-android --variant=targetRelease
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

for ios `--scheme`  is there

```
 react-native run-ios --scheme "TargetName"
```

for other arguments, I just extracted the runIos.js file from local-cli

here is the data,

```
{
  name: 'run-ios',
  description: 'builds your app and starts it on iOS simulator',
  func: runIOS,
  examples: [
  {
    desc: 'Run on a different simulator, e.g. iPhone 5',
    cmd: 'react-native run-ios --simulator "iPhone 5"',
  },
  {
    desc: 'Pass a non-standard location of iOS directory',
    cmd: 'react-native run-ios --project-path "./app/ios"',
  },
  {
    desc: "Run on a connected device, e.g. Max's iPhone",
    cmd: 'react-native run-ios --device "Max\'s iPhone"',
  },
  {
    desc: 'Run on the AppleTV simulator',
    cmd: 'react-native run-ios --simulator "Apple TV"  --scheme "helloworld-tvOS"',
  }
  ],
  options: [{
    command: '--simulator [string]',
    description: 'Explicitly set simulator to use',
    default: 'iPhone 6',
  } , {
    command: '--configuration [string]',
    description: 'Explicitly set the scheme configuration to use',
  } , {
    command: '--scheme [string]',
    description: 'Explicitly set Xcode scheme to use',
  }, {
    command: '--project-path [string]',
    description: 'Path relative to project root where the Xcode project '
      + '(.xcodeproj) lives. The default is \'ios\'.',
    default: 'ios',
  }, {
    command: '--device [string]',
    description: 'Explicitly set device to use by name.  The value is not required if you have a single device connected.',
  }, {
    command: '--udid [string]',
    description: 'Explicitly set device to use by udid',
  }, {
    command: '--no-packager',
    description: 'Do not launch packager while building',
  }, {
    command: '--verbose',
    description: 'Do not use xcpretty even if installed',
  },{
    command: '--port [number]',
    default: process.env.RCT_METRO_PORT || 8081,
    parse: (val: string) => Number(val),
  }],
};
```

Comment: thanks react-native run-ios --scheme "TargetName" works for me

Answer (score 10):

You can change the schema in XCode as explained in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/CustomizingYourExperienceThroughXcodeSchemes/CustomizingYourExperienceThroughXcodeSchemes.html).

Or, you can execute `react-native run-ios --scheme "Release"`.

Comment: thanks, this works, got it from the accepted answer.